# postgresql call a function repeatedly and combine results

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

In postgresql, I have a function which takes in an userid and returns the set of hobbies they prefer.

I want to call the function repeatedly for different userid and combine the result to get distinct hobbies.

Want this in a single sql statement.
Function Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usermultiplehobby() 
RETURNS TABLE (hobbyid "hobby".id%type,  hobbyname "hobby".name%type) AS 
$$
WITH user_hobby AS (
   SELECT hobby(userid) as f
   FROM   "user"
   where userid in (2,4,6,7,5)
   ) 
select distinct (fr.f).id as hobbyid, (fr.f).name as hobbyname from  user_hobby fr;
 $$ 
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Comment: I tried it and wrote a separate function, but want it in a single sql statement. Just wanted to know if there is a way for doing it.

Comment: Please show us your function code

Comment: What is `hobby(userid)` doing?

Comment: it is a function, that list hobbies info like id and name based on certain preferences of a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want to do? Perhaps rephrase the question using relevant portions of this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hobby_data;

CREATE TEMP TABLE hobby_data (user_id integer, hobbies text[]);

INSERT INTO hobby_data (user_id, hobbies) VALUES
    (1, ARRAY['chess', 'tennis']),
    (2, ARRAY['chess', 'philately']),
    (3, ARRAY['knitting', 'car restoration']);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hobbies(user_id INTEGER) 
RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$
   SELECT hobbies
   FROM hobby_data
   WHERE user_id = $1;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql;

WITH users AS (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM hobby_data
    WHERE user_id IN (1,2))
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(get_hobbies(user_id))
FROM users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Function Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usermultiplehobby() 
RETURNS TABLE (hobbyid "hobby".id%type,  hobbyname "hobby".name%type) AS 
$$
WITH user_hobby AS (
   SELECT hobby(userid) as f
   FROM   "user"
   where userid in (2,4,6,7,5)
   ) 
select distinct (fr.f).id as hobbyid, (fr.f).name as hobbyname from  user_hobby fr;
 $$ 
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```